# Tampered with System Volume Information... Now I Need Default Permissions. Doh

Tags: windows-7, permissions, acl

I'm using Win7, I changed my SYS-VOL-INFO folder permissions to take a peek inside, and I forgot to take note of the default permisisons (ACL's).  I found a website, that isn't Microsoft, that claimed to know the default permissions.  Don't know if it's reliable or not.  So, I'm wondering what are the official default permissions (please cite your source) ?  Also, I'm wondering if by chance that SFC (System File Checker) can reset these permissions or is there an automated way to do so?

Comment: tweaking.com's [All In One Repair](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html) can restore file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care? Just leave it as it is.

You can also simple delete the whole directory, it comes back by itself right away. I did that often, no negative effects:

1. take *ownership* for the directory and all files below: rightclick/Properties/Advanced/Change Owner, 'Replace Owner on sub containers and objects'
2. remove the hidden and system attributes (ATTRIB -H -S "C:\System Volume Information").
3. remove it all with RMDIR /s "C:\System Volume Information"

Comment: It wont let me delete it.  Even if I switch permissions to full control.  A message asks me to delete, it acts like it does, but it remains.  I just don't want any issues with the OS or programs... should any need access to the folders.

Comment: I just went through it, Windows 10 seems to have an extra level of stopping in there. see updated answer.